# Angular-NVD3 yDomain/forceY and transitions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

In a simple Angular-NVD3 line chart, I'm using forceY to set the domain manually to add a "padding" to the y datas to make the chart more readable.

The problem is that setting this will stop the chart from animating when I change the data. Here is a Codepen showing the problem: 
http://codepen.io/mvidailhet/pen/RpKBMz?editors=1010

I tried doing the same thing using only nvd3 and the transitions work: http://codepen.io/mvidailhet/pen/QpdZvo?editors=1010

Does anyone have a solution for this problem ?

```
forceY(currentDomain);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: OK, so while making the example in Codepen, I realized that it worked with NVD3 and that the problem came from Angular-NVD3. So I edited my question